# I need information about exactly where to report a bug in Gnome Flashback Metacity. All efforts so far have been incorrect

Tags: metacity

I need information about exactly where to report a bug in Gnome Flashback Metacity.  Several efforts so far have been incorrect.

I have a problem with a constantly busy hard drive after a few hours of use that locks up the system, requiring a system reset and restart to fix, which works for another few hours, then repeats.

The best response I have so far about the log files I supplied is :

```
--------------------
 " [ebassi]     ebassi Emmanuele Bassi GNOME Team
September 28
You’re using gnome-panel, a GNOME 2 era component that is currently only part of the “Flashback” session, which is not part of GNOME.
Those are critical warnings coming from gnome-panel; they indicate a bug. Please open an issue on the project’s issue tracker.
-------------------
```

A specific URL for this issue tracker location would be EXTREMELY appreciated !

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

[Gnome Flashback Issue Tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues).

It's referenced on the [Gnome Flashback wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback), under "Reporting Bugs".